# Pandas removing duplicate range of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi all I have the following dataframe:

```
df1
      WL       WM      WH        WP      
1     low    medium   high   premium
2     26       26      15        14
3     32       32      18        29 
4     41       41      19        42
5     apple    dog     fur      napkins          
6     orange   cat     tesla    earphone
7     NaN      rat     tobias   controller
8     NaN      NaN     phone
9     low      medium  high            
10     1        3       5
11     2        4       6
12    low      medium  high
13     4        8       10
14     5        9       11
```

Is there a way to remove low + 2 rows such that the output is such:

```
df1
      WL       WM      WH        WP      
1     low    medium   high   premium
2     26       26      15        14
3     32       32      18        29 
4     41       41      19        42
5     apple    dog     fur      napkins          
6     orange   cat     tesla    earphone
7     NaN      rat     tobias   controller
8     NaN      NaN     phone
```

Unfortunately the code must be dynamic because I have multiple dataframes and the placement for 'low' is different in each. My initial attempt:

```
df1 = df1[~df1.iloc[:,0].isin(['LOW'])+2].reset_index(drop=True)
```

however this is not quite what I am looking for. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#get index values where low
a = df.index[df.iloc[:,0] == 'low']

size = 2
#all index values (without first [1:])
#min is for last rows of df for avoid select non existed values
arr = [np.arange(i, min(i+size+1,len(df)+1)) for i in a[1:]]
idx = np.unique(np.concatenate(arr))
print (idx)
[ 9 10 11 12 13 14]

#remove rows
df = df.drop(idx)
print (df)
       WL      WM      WH          WP
1     low  medium    high     premium
2      26      26      15          14
3      32      32      18          29
4      41      41      19          42
5   apple     dog     fur     napkins
6  orange     cat   tesla    earphone
7     NaN     rat  tobias  controller
8     NaN     NaN   phone         NaN
```

Comment: it is window size

Comment: need remove 2 rows, so `size=2`

Comment: this is really close! however when I print idx, it doesnt quite seem to capture the last instance of low + 2 rows. Any idea of how I may fix it?

Comment: Is index unique? `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` can help for it.

Comment: that fixed it, thanks! If I wanted to modify 'a' to include a list of words, how would I do that? @jezrael